# Can you manually reload?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

I haven't found any way to manually reload my pistol in game.

Is there actually a way to do this or do you have to just keep firing until you run out before you reload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** you can manual Reload.

Just press <kbd>**L3**</kbd> (if you don't know is pressing down the Left Sticker.)

By pressing down <kbd>**R3**</kbd> and keeping it pressed you can remove the HUD.